# PhpSpreadsheet cell validation rules to disallow invalid entry

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I am using PhpSpreadsheet within a Laravel app to output a spreadsheet that needs fairly strict controls around it in order to allow that same spreadsheet to be input back into the app after data has been entered.

I can control the data types and even have a nice pop-up message when a user enters an incorrect type such as this:

[image]

However, once the user clicks OK or Cancel, the incorrectly formatted text is allowed to remain in the cell.  **Is there a way to not only flag it for the user, but disallow the incorrect entry altogether**?

Current example code:

```
if($sub['type'] === 'date') {
    $ws->getStyle('C' . $row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(
        \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DMYSLASH
    );
    $objValidation = $ws->getCell('C' . $row)->getDataValidation();
    $objValidation->setType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::TYPE_DATE);
    $objValidation->setErrorStyle(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
    $objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);
    $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
    $objValidation->setError('Please enter a date in the format d/m/yy only.');
}
```

I'm guessing I've missed something in the PhpSpreadsheet manual?  I've looked into the base code on some of the methods like `setAllowBlank`, but I'm likely not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still couldn't find this in the docs (though I'm sure it is there somewhere).  But once I was able to figure out where to look in the **PhpSpreadsheet** code, I found it.  Very elegant solution from **PhpSpreadsheet**... I just couldn't see it in the area of base code I was looking into!

Easy fix, change one word:

```
$objValidation->setErrorStyle(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
```

Becomes:

```
$objValidation->setErrorStyle(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::STYLE_STOP);
```

The big '!' on the popup gave me a clue to look at their style code rather than commands code.  This brings up the same box, but with an 'X' *and prevents changing the cell if not valid*, which is exactly what I wanted.

Hopefully helps someone else in future.

Answer (score 1):

Why not blanking the cell after validation error there is an [isValid function](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.3.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/DataValidator.html). The code can look like:

```
if(! PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidator::isValid($yourCell)){
    $yourCell->setValue("");
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  I'm upvoting this, as it looks like a valid solution, but not for me - too many pieces to fix, as I want to to display previous.  After poking around the whole PhpSpreadsheet code, I found a little better solution (for me).  Thanks again!