# PhpSpreadsheet cell validation rules to disallow invalid entry for date

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using maatwebsite to export sample excel file to import data. i need to set validation for date in excel while entry.
I've tried ref to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028758/phpspreadsheet-cell-validation-rules-to-disallow-invalid-entry) as well but it does not allow dd/mm/yyyy format. it shows error 'Date is not allowed' always. any thing you enter.
[image]

```
$event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle('H2')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(
    \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY
);

// set date for first data row
$validation1 = $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getCell('H2')->getDataValidation();
$validation1->setType( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::TYPE_DATE );
$validation1->setErrorStyle( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::STYLE_STOP );
$validation1->setAllowBlank(true);
$validation1->setShowInputMessage(true);
$validation1->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$validation1->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$validation1->setError('Date is not allowed!');
$validation1->setPromptTitle('Allowed input');
$validation1->setPrompt('Only Date format dd/mm/yyyy allowed.');
```

Comment: If you are using Laravel, Laravel excel is one of the best packages out there use that instead next time :)

Comment: if you can explain how to achieve my requirement then it will be helpful @mrhn

Comment: I will try :) maybe over the weekend, else ping me if i forget it